# PHP: Mostrar resultados de consulta SQL omite un resultado

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy un poco desconcertado con un situación que se acaba de presentar.

Poseo una tabla MySQL llamada "clientes", ya se imaginarán su utilidad.

En una sección del sistema que se llama "Listar todos los clientes" hago una consulta simple del tipo:

```
$consultaClientes = "SELECT * FROM clientes";
$resultadoClientes = mysqli_query($conexion, $consultaClientes);
```

para posteriormente mostrarlos en una tabla HTML con el siguiente algoritmo:

```
while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultadoClientes)) {
    // Muestra en pantalla de los resultados
    // Para esta situación se muestran TODOS los registros
}
```

El problema surge en una sección diferente. La sección "Nueva venta" es un formulario que permitirá registrar una nueva venta donde intervendrán las tablas "clientes", "productos" y "ventas".
Dentro de esta sección estoy intentando listar todos los nombres de los clientes en un:

```
<select>
    <option value="id cliente 1">Nombre cliente 1</option>
    <option value="id cliente 2">Nombre cliente 2</option>
</select>
```

Con el fin de seleccionar a qué cliente se le está realizando la venta.
Para esto ejecuto el mismo código que en "Listar todos los clientes" pero me omite un resultado, que sería el primero de la tabla, el de la id mas pequeña.
Lo mismo sucede con los productos. En la sección similar a "Listar clientes" pero para productos, muestra en la tabla todos los productos de la tabla.
Pero en esta sección, como digo, omite un resultado. Probé hacer esto:

```
mysqli_num_rows($resultadoClientes);
```

Hice esta prueba en ambas secciones para ver si es que no estaban arrojando cantidad de resultados diferentes pero no, en ambas me sale el mismo número de filas encontradas, tan solo que en una omite un resultado. Dejo el código de "Nueva venta":

```
<select class="form-control form-control-lg" name="nombre_cliente">
    <option disabled selected>Elegir cliente</option>
    <?php
    while($filaCliente = mysqli_fetch_array($resultadoClientes)){ ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $filaCliente['id_cliente']; ?>"><?php echo $filaCliente['nombre_cliente']; ?></option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Acá la consulta:

```
$consultaClientes = "SELECT * FROM clientes";
$resultadoClientes = mysqli_query($conexion, $consultaClientes);

if(!$resultadoClientes){
    die('Error al extraer los datos de la tabla de clientes.');
}
```

Bueno, espero haber expresado lo suficientemente bien mi problema. Como les digo, me desconcierta un poco porque los códigos son exactamente iguales pero en el caso de listar los nombres en un < select > de html, omite un resultado. Eso mismo sucede para con los productos. Al ejecutar mysqli_num_rows() también devuelve el mismo resultado de filas que en la sección de listar en una tabla pero bueno, ustedes ya saben. Muchas gracias por haber llegado hasta aquí. Saludos.

**Actualización: Agrego capturas:**

[image: Foto de la tabla en phpmyadmin]

**Foto de la vista en la web:**

[image: Foto de la vista]

Ahora le agregué un < option > más. Para asegurar la cantidad de resultados recibidos: Es la línea siguiente:

```
<option disabled>Cantidad de resultados: <?php echo mysqli_num_rows($resultadoClientes); ?></option>
```

Que claro, va debajo de la línea mostrada anteriormente con el atributo selected y que muestra el texto "Elegir cliente:". Como se ve, me omite el dato de mi cliente ficticio "Carlos Solari". Sucede exactamente al listar la tabla "productos".

Comment: Revisa que no estés leyendo un registro con `mysqli_fetch_array( ... )` antes de comenzar el ciclo.

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el código seguido para ver el orden que sigue?

Comment: De casualidad el nombre del primer cliente lo copiaste de un excel?, podrías verificar eso o el nombre del producto, sucede que a veces cuando copias de excel los espacios en blanco tienen una codificación que no concuerda con el cotejamiento de la tabla y pone un signo de interrogación la base de datos y luego cuando tratas de verlo o editarlo no te deja, prueba borrar los espacios y me cuentas.

Comment: La otra opción es que pongas ver código fuente de la página para ver si ese select te arroja algún error desde php.

Comment: lo otro que veo es que while($filaCliente = mysqli_fetch_array($resultadoClientes)) le falta un parametro, while($filaCliente = mysqli_fetch_array($resultadoClientes,MYSQL_ASSOC)), prueba con eso también.